# Nexus: removing repository

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I accidently removed a hosted snapshot repository from Nexus containing a few artifacts needed by other developers on my team. Fine, I'll be able to recreate it fairly easy, but when I tried to add the repository again with the same name as the one I removed, the "Upload Artifact" tab did not show. I tried to clean the cache and reindex the public and public snapshot repos, but that didn't help. I also tried setting an alternative storage path by entering an alternative path on "Override Local Storage Location", same result.
Will I have to create a brand new repository with a different name and change all repository reference in my projects?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create the new repo without any problem. It's possible you where inheriting permissions to this repo via a group and when you made the new repo you didn't add it to the group.

Also, all delete operations in Nexus simply move files to the sonatype-work/nexus/trash so you could have just copied all those files back directly on the disk after recreating the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I think I noticed that snapshot repositories do not have the Artifact Upload tab, so possibly you created it as a snapshot repo?